# Why would a switch have 1 12-2 wire run to it and the white and black are both hot?

Tags: switch

I am trying to install exhaust fan where there was a light before.
The switch has 1 12-2 wire to it and both white and black are hot.
Can anyone explain my observations?

Comment: How are you determining that both are hot?

Comment: Are you familiar with a "switch loop"?  Do you want separate control of switch and fan and how do you feel about fishing a new cable?

Answer (score 4):

That is usually called a switch loop.  The white should be marked with black tape/paint showing always hot and the black is switch hot.

Power cable goes to the box for the light, the white wire is connected to black wire of power cable, and goes to the switch.

The black wire from the switch goes to the light and is connected to the black wire of the light.

The light goes on and off by the switch.

New electrical code wants /3 wire cable so there is a neutral wire in the switch box for newer smart switches that require neutral wire.